# Recreate digitally an ink smudge/bleeding/watercolor-y thrashed out image?

Tags: images, effects, texture

I've seen these recently on Instagram and was wondering if it would be possible to recreate such digitally? (because I suspect they did it digitally, even though that could also have be done analogously via real watercolor maybe).

link to images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgXCy.jpg

Comment: This is almost too specific. Really hard to say without seeing the original assets. It's art. Could involve a mix of analogue and digital techniques. It would be easier if you already had some texture and image which you have tried to mix, but couldn't get quite right.

Comment: Might be better to ask the instagram user who was responsible for posting them.